# Conjugações do verbo aprazer

Tags: verbos

Compreende-se que o verbo [`chover`](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/verbos-portugueses/chover) tenha as suas limitações com referência às conjugações nas diferentes pessoas. Todavia não o compreendo para o verbo `aprazer`. Quer o [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/Conjugar/aprazer), quer a [Porto Editora](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/verbos-portugueses/aprazer), registam apenas as terceiras pessoas do singular e do plural.

Não estará correto, portanto, referir "apraz-me"? Qual a denominação para este tipo de verbos? Não é este verbo sempre reflexivo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perguntei também no site ciberdúvidas e obtive hoje a resposta.

> Trata-se de um verbo defetivo, e o exemplo que apresenta está correto, pois confirma a defetividade do verbo, a qual tem fatores históricos. Com efeito, "apraz" é uma forma da 3.ª pessoa do singular do presente do indicativo do verbo "aprazer".
>
> Note que a sequência "apraz-me" não configura um verbo reflexivo. Na verdade, o verbo "aprazer" é transitivo indireto, isto é, seleciona um complemento indireto:
>
> (i) este fato não apraz ao príncipe -> este fato não lhe apraz
>
> Em (i), vemos que o verbo tem um complemento indireto pronominalizável como "lhe". Se o complemento se refrir ao sujeito do enunciado, o pronome é "me":
>
> (ii) este fato não me apraz.
>
> Quer em (i) quer em (ii), os pronomes não são reflexivos.

De facto, não me apercebi que o verbo não é reflexivo, pois quando refiro que "apraz-me", digo implicitamente que "*algo* me apraz", sendo *algo* neste caso o sujeito da oração, sendo que "eu" é o objeto indireto (apraz "a mim").

Muito diferente de um verbo reflexivo, como por exemplo "observar-se", pois quando digo "observo-me" é equivalente a dizer "eu observo-me", ou seja, o sujeito e o objeto direito são a mesma pessoa.

#### Verbo defetivo

> Termo que designa o verbo cuja conjugação é incompleta, uma vez que não flexiona em todas as formas possíveis num paradigma flexional regular. São exemplos de verbos defetivos: reaver (que só se usa nas formas em que o verbo haver tem v: reavemos, reaveis, reavia, reouve, etc.), colorir, abolir, falir, extorquir, retorquir, etc.

> O Dicionário Terminológico distingue dois tipos de verbos defetivos:

> **Verbos defetivos unipessoais**: verbos que exigem um sujeito específico e que portanto são utilizados apenas na 3.ª pessoa do singular e do plural. Regra geral, estes verbos exprimem vozes de animais: ladrar (ex: o cão ladra, o cavalo relincha, as rãs coaxam), etc.

> **Verbos defetivos impessoais**: verbos que apresentam um sujeito nulo expletivo, pelo que apenas se conjugam na 3. ª pessoa do singular, salvo quando usados em sentido figurado. Regra geral, este verbos exprimem fenómenos atmosféricos: amanhecer (ex: amanheceu às 6h), chover (ex: choveu muito esta noite), nevar (ex: neva no inverno), trovejar (ex: trovejou ontem?), relampejar, etc. O verbo haver quando significa existir também é impessoal (ex: havia muitos problemas no país).

Fonte: https://www.infopedia.pt/$defetivo